# Explain why the hypothesis of Picard's Theorem hold in this case

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> Using Picard's Theorem, show that
>   $$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2 \qquad \quad y(0)=1$$
>   has a unique solution in the rectangle $R=[0,0.5] \times [0,2]$.

---

**Picard's Theorem:**

The differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y) \qquad \quad y(a)=b$$
has a unique solution in the rectangle $R=\{(x,y):|x-a|≤h, \; |y-b|≤k \}$ if:

(i) $f$ is continuous in $R$

(ii) $M := \max _{(x,y) \in R} |f(x,y)|$ exists and satisfies $Mh≤k$; and

(iii) $f$ is Lipshitz in $R$

---

I have shown that the differential equation satisfies conditions (i) and (iii), and also that $M$ exists.

Clearly, $M=2^2=4$ in this case, $h=0.5$ and $k=1$, but it is not true that
$$4 \times 0.5 ≤ 1$$
Have I misunderstood something about Picard's Theorem, or is there something wrong with this question?

Answer (score 2):

$h$ is not 0.5 here, but 0.25. $R$ in this example can be understood as $\{(x,y):(|x-0|\le0.25,|y-1|\le1\}$.

Comment: But the initial condition is $y(0)=1$, so shouldn't it be $|x-0|≤0.5$?

Comment: @glowstonetrees Maybe you wrote the definition wrong.